# Why does retrieving the property name on a anonymous type give the following result?

Tags: c#, reflection

A junior co-worker of mine managed to write very scary, scary code.

```
printJob.Type = item[LocalFunctions.GetName(new { printJob.Type })].ToString();

 public static string GetName<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            return typeof(T).GetProperties()[0].Name;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What is you gues what will GetName will output? **It will output "Type"**!
I just don't get how this is possible. My first thought is that MS will create an anonymous type with  property that has the same name as the property from which the value came from (compiler magic?). As this cannot possibly be a supported feature, I advised my junior co-worker to not use things he cannot understand.

But that leaves the question open: **How is this possible?**

Comment: sounds like he may not be your junior for long!

Comment: @Sam: No everything's fine, I'm aware this is part of the learning process :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous types infer property names unless they are specified:

> If you do not specify member names in the anonymous type, the compiler
>   gives the anonymous type members the same name as the property being
>   used to initialize them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

The compiler then infers the type for the generic at compile time - so `typeof(T)` works. It is fully supported, even if the code is fragile. What happens when someone refactors the name of the property?

I'd also say it's inadvisable to advise people on topics you don't have an answer to yourself - this is the source of many a www.thedailywtf.com article ;-)

Personally I'd still remove this in favour of more robust code, instead of assuming the property name is always going to be the same.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this advice. " I advised my junior co-worker to not use things he cannot understand.". If you can't explain why it even works (because it was copy pasted from some forum), you shouldn't use it. Thanks for the answer, through.

Comment: @AlexMaker True, I was just being facetious. Your comment on it "not possibly being a supported feature" and subsequent advice, followed by the exact same question you were implying the junior couldn't answer just struck me as funny. There is nothing wrong with the advice per se, but that assumes the junior actually *couldn't* understand the code and that it wasn't just your assumption that they couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the compiler (not MS) does when creating anonymous types. It uses The type, name and order of the supplied parameters to construct a new type. This is fully supported and intended to be that way, so there's no reason not to use it.

The compiler has all the information available to do this. It sees what name and type the properties you used to initialize it have (such as `printJob.Type`) and can use that information to generate the anonymous type for you.

See here for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx